# List of every integer except 2 with list comprehensions

Tags: python

Is there a simpler way to achieve this with list comprehensions? I'm new to them and currently trying to improve my coding:

```
list = []
for k in range(1000):
    if k != num1 and k != num2:
        listToFade.append(k)
```

basically in 'list' you have all the numbers from 0 to 999 except 2

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a list comprehension version of your code:

```
list=[i for i in range(1000) if i not in [num1, num2]]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this:

```
listToFade = [k for k in range(1000) if k != num1 and k != num2]
```

You can also use [filter()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#filter):

```
list(filter(lambda k: k != num1 and k != num2, range(1000)))
```

Answer (score 1):

```
def crea_lista(*num):
    return [i for i in range(1000) if i not in num]

l = crea_lista(2,5)
print(l)
```